# Django pluralize person as people

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, pluralize

trying to output the correct plural value in Django template when count is more than 1.

`<p>{{ review.markers.helpful.count }} person{{ reviews.markers.helpful.count|length|pluralize }} found this helpful</p>`

still returns `1 persons` or `2 persons` instead of `1 person` and `2 people`

any help to fix this in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the suffixes of the two forms with:

```
pe{{ reviews.markers.helpful.count|pluralize:"rson,eople" }}
```

or simpler:

```
{{ reviews.markers.helpful.count|pluralize:"person,people" }}
```

Comment: already tried the above methods. still not working

Comment: @coder-stix: but you should not use `|length`...

Comment: not using ```|length```. used the solutions above, still not working as it should